# Time data values in R

Tags: r

how can I have a data set of only time intervals (no dates) in R, like the following:

`TREATMENT_A TREATMENT_B`

`1:01:12 0:05:00`

`0:34:56 1:08:09`

and compute mean times, etc, and draw boxplots with time intervals in the y-axis?

I am new to R, and I searched for this but found no example in the net.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chron-package has a 'times' class that supports arithmetic. You could also do all of that with POSIXct objects and format the date-time output to not include the date. I thought `axis.POSIXct` function has a `format` argument that should let you have time outputs. However, it does not seem to get dispatched properly, so I needed to construct the axis "by hand."

```
dft <- data.frame(x= factor( sample(1:2, 100, repl=TRUE)), 
                  y= Sys.time()+rnorm(100)*4000 )
boxplot(y~x, data=dft, yaxt='n')
axis(2, at=seq(from=range(dft$y)[1], to =range(dft$y)[2], by=3000) , 
         labels=format.POSIXct(seq(from=range(dft$y)[1], to =range(dft$y)[2], by=3000), 
                                 format ="%H:%M:%S") )
```

[image]

There did turn out to be an appropriate method, `Axis.POSIXt` (to which I thought `boxplot` should have been turning for plotting, but it did not seem to recognize the class of the 'y' argument):

```
boxplot(y~x, data=dft, yaxt='n')
Axis(side=2, x=range(dft$y), format ="%H:%M:%S")
```

[image]

Regarding your request for something "simpler", take a look at theis ggplot2 based solution, using the dft dataframe defined above with POSIXct times. (I did try with the chron-times object but got a message saying ggplot did not support that class):

```
require(ggplot2); p <- ggplot(dft, aes(x,y))
p + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: I have installed chron and tried `tms <- times(c("23:03:20", "22:29:56", "01:03:30", "18:21:03", "16:56:26"))`and `boxplot(tms)` but the values in y-axis are numeric not time data. What can I do to have time data in the y-axis of the boxplot?

Comment: You can use yaxt='n' as shown above and then add an axis which will be in units of days with `axis(side=2, x=range(dft$y) )`. You can look at the very interesting approach of axis.times with `getAnywhere(axis.times)`.

Comment: Is there a simpler way using the `tms` data instead of yours? Also, can the times in the y-axis be in the horizontal for readability? (I am a newbie, having started today!)

Comment: The `las=2` parameter should allow you to rotate the labels. I'm not sure how I can make it any "simpler" than a single `axis` call.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear: what I meant as simpler was having something like `boxplot(tms, ...)`, that is, making boxplots using chron data types.

Comment: You can use ggplot2 for POSIXct objects. See above.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the "lubridate" package, and the "hms" function within it.